PHP Curl Seems to Block Server Response Resulting in a Timeout
I've been chasing my tail on this one all day. I have an instance of Adobe Commerce (formerly Magento 2) running on an AWS server. I'm using Adobe Commerce's Curl adapter to make a server-to-server call to an external API. Usually this call is executed without any issues and the response is handled correctly.
                $curl = $this->curlFactory->create();
                $curl->setConfig(
                        [
                                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                                CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $this->getUserAgent(),
                                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                        ]
                );
                $curl->write('POST', $url, '1.1', $this->getHeaders($payload), $payload);
                $curlResponse = $curl->read();

                $statusCode = $curl->getInfo(CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                $headerLength = $curl->getInfo(CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);

                $curl->close();

However I've identified cases where reading the response from the server yields a timeout error. I have access to the server that is sending the response and I have confirmed that it is indeed sending the response. And after using tcpdump on the client server, I've verified that the packets are being received. But here's the thing: the packets aren't received until immediately after the $curl->read() function times out. It seems like the $curl->read() request is blocking the incoming TCP packets and I cannot figure out why.
Here is a readout of the relevant lines from tcpdump when the timeout is set to 30s
22:21:10.658883 [redacted] Flags [.], ack 1506, win 497, length 0
22:21:41.091462 [redacted] Flags [P.], seq 4531:7193, ack 1506, win 501, length 2662

Notice the almost exactly 30s gap between the packets. When I changed the timeout to 20s I got the following:
22:23:26.620425 [redacted] Flags [.], ack 1506, win 497, length 0
22:23:46.340089 [redacted] Flags [P.], seq 1506:1530, ack 4531, win 457, length 24

Again, notice almost exactly 20s gap between packets. Just for fun, here's what happened when I set timeout to 17s:
22:27:54.870698 [redacted] Flags [.], ack 1506, win 495, length 0
22:28:11.739022 [redacted] Flags [P.], seq 1506:1530, ack 4531, win 457, length 24

Boom! 17 seconds almost on the nose.
It seems to me that while the Curl adapter is trying to read the response from the server, it's actually blocking the server's response from being received. This doesn't happen on every request. It is intermittent but also replicable given a few tries.
Does anyone have any advice about how to resolve this issue? Thank you!
I tried to send a curl request using Adobe Commerce's Curl adapter. I expected to receive the response from the server. Instead, the response from the server was delayed until the $curl->read() function timed out and then was immediately received.

It well depends on what the nature of the server-to-server API call is. If the Adobe Commerce operation depends on the success or failure of that server-to-server call, telling the client that there is timeout (and perhaps some clean up in Adobe Commerce) is the preferred way.

Do you have access to the coding of the other end of this server-to-server call?

Also, is this server-to-server call actually calling the same server of your Adobe Commerce, the same backend database, or even calling the same Adobe Commerce installation itself?

No, the API call is to a totally separate, independent server that is unrelated to the server I have Adobe Commerce installed on. What I'd expect to happen, and what does happen in most cases, is for Magento to make the Curl request and then receive the response. But what seems to be happening in these cases is the Curl request is blocking the response from being received until timeout. And then the packets immediately arraive

In your case, is the success of the server-to-server NOT essential to the Adobe Commerce operation?

It is essential that we know the outcome of the operation in our Adobe Commerce instance. If we're sending an API request to modify an external resource and that resource is modified, but the response is lost because it hasn't been read but the Curl adapter, then that puts our Adobe Commerce instance out of sync with the external resource.

Have you tried to do the POST request with simple CURL functions?
Example,
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->getUserAgent());
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt(
    $ch, 
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
    $this->getHeaders($payload),
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($payload));

// Receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

